# "Ought" omission of "to"

Tags: syntax, morphosyntax

Does anybody know anything about the distribution of the modal "ought" without "to" (in other words, "ought" taking the base infinitive).  Eg:

They ought to go home.

vs.

They ought go home.

Is "ought" without "to" an occasional variant?  Is it archaic?  Is it regional?

The reason I want to know is b/c I teach ESL, and would like to tell my students accurate information.  Thank you.

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://english.stackexchange.com/a/75927/19046

Comment: "ought" omitting "to" = "ugh"

Comment: Thank you everybody.  Those responses ought be of great help to me!

Answer (score 2):

In present-day English *ought* may behave like a 'modal' verb, taking an unmarked infinitive, only in negatives and questions, not in ordinary declaratives:

> Ought I take that seriously?
>   You ought not take that seriously. *BUT*
>   You ought **to** take that seriously.

But even in negatives and questions the unmarked infinitive is not always required; for many speakers a marked infinitive is acceptable, too:

> Ought I to take that seriously?
>   You ought not to take that seriously.

---

ADDED: 
Even more likely in US speech is the "melded" form *oughta*:

> Oughta we take that seriously?
>   You oughta not take that seriously.

And this tolerates what looks like lexicalization but is probably better understood as modal stacking:

> Do we oughta take that seriously?
>   You didn't oughta take that seriously.

---

In any case, this is a question of declining importance: use of *ought* has decreased markedly in the last couple of generations.

Comment: This is a good answer, but like @aml mentioned, a bare *ought* isn't really modal; the *to* is just elided.

Comment: @pydsigner I was careful to say that it "behaves" like a modal, not that it is a modal :)  And I've added a bit on *oughta*, which I think **is** a modal.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my answer.
To understand 'ought', I will coin a word class called 'control verbal'.
A control verbal has an event as its direct object.  The subject of this sub-event will be 'raised to object', or it will be omitted (raised to subject) if it matches the calling subject.  The verb of the sub-event will be cast to infinitive (possibly bare) or cast to participle.  A 'pure' modal (like 'should') always controls by 'raising to subject' and 'bare infinitive'.  The 'impure' modal 'ought' differs in that the infinitive may be marked (by 'to').  A control verb (like 'need') is a control verbal that has its own 'action', as well as controlling a sub-event.  The infinitive marker may be deleted when the control is negated, making it parse like a modal: "He needs to drink, but he need not eat."

Old answer:
'Ought' does not really become modal when the infinitive marker 'to' is elided.  Rather, 'ought' is still a 'control verb', but the controlled verb '[to] go' is reduced to a bare infinitive.  This is also true of control verbs like 'need' and 'dare'.  Because it works with so few verbs, I would call it archaic.

Comment: *Need* and *ought* are raising verbs aren't they? *There needn't be another referendum*, for example.

Comment: Hold on! "Ought" is unquestionably a modal in any of its uses. I don't think the fact that there is a growing tendency for it to be constructed with a bare infinitival in non-affirmatives changes its status as a modal. "Need" and "dare" can be modal auxiliaries or lexical verbs.

Comment: @Araucaria - 'I need/want him to go' is an example of 'raising to object', but 'I need/want [myself] to go' is not, as far as I know.  We could use some better terms for 'control/raising' verbs.  Change 'need/want' to 'ought' and you will see that the raising to object version is not allowed.

Comment: @BillJ - True modals (like 'should') never take a marked infinitive ('*I should to go.').  Any word that takes a marked infinitive is not a modal, and it is simpler to assume that the infinitive marker can be elided than that the word shifts from control verb to modal.

Comment: @aml "Ought" is generally interchangeable with "should", exhibiting deontic modality, as in _You should / ought to tell your mother_, epistemic modality in _The next turning on the left should / ought to be King Street_, and ambiguous between the two in _Ed should / ought to do better this time_. The evidence seems overwhelming to me.

Comment: @BillJ - Are you talking BrE?  In AmE we NEVER say '... should to...'.  If there is a grammar that allows 'should to' then I would be inclined to say that 'should' had migrated from modal to control verb.

Comment: @aml Ah, slight misunderstanding. I meant the alternants are "should ..." or "ought to ...". If only underlining was possible

Comment: @BillJ - Ah yes; you meant "ought to" is like "should".  The difference between modal and control verb then depends on storage methods, which are speculative.  Since the number of control verbs ('want', 'try', 'have', etc) is greater than a dozen, I suspect they are not stored like modals, and I still think the elided 'to' in '...ought [to] do...' does not make 'ought' into a modal.

Comment: Consider the modality because that's where the answer is. If "ought (+ _to_) is not a modal, then nor is "should", and that would be silly.

Comment: @BillJ - You are right. 'Ought' is not a verb.  It is a 'control verbal', which is what modals are.  It is a synonym of 'should', but doesn't quite share all of the properties of a canonical modal.  Modals are on the spectrum of control verbs, but they only 'control'.  You are right that 'ought' can control another verb, but never be controlled by another verb or modal.  Thanks for making me think.  (Modals probably use the same storage methods as control verbs.)

Comment: @BillJ - 'Ought' is semantically identical with 'should', but it is not grammatically identical.  That is why I can't accept it as a modal (since syntax trumps semantics when dealing with grammar).